# Android: Button with Ad (onAdLoaded)

Tags: android, button, visible, interstitial

I am adding ad to the Activity in a way that the button going to the next Activity is set to be Invisible until the ad is finished loading.

```
public void showAd_andSetGoButton()   
{   
    if (isNetworkAvailable() == true)
    {
        button_go.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
        button_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mPublisherInterstitialAd = new PublisherInterstitialAd(this);
        mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(MY_PUBLISHER_ID);

        // Create an ad request.
        PublisherAdRequest.Builder publisherAdRequestBuilder = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder();

        // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
        publisherAdRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(PublisherAdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

        // Set an AdListener.
        mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onAdLoaded() 
           {
                // Toast.makeText(First.this, "The interstitial is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
               button_go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
               button_loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           }

           @Override
           public void onAdClosed() 
           {
                go_action();
           }
       });

       // Start loading the ad now so that it is ready by the time the user is ready to go to the next level.
       mPublisherInterstitialAd.loadAd(publisherAdRequestBuilder.build());          
    }
    else
    {
        button_go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    }
}
```

### Question:

The above codes work well. However, I know that sometimes even when sending out request for ad, no ad will be returned due to some reasons such as lack of inventory. I would like to ask when such case arises, will the `onAdLoaded()` be properly returned such that the button_go will be visible if no ad can be loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this override function in `AdListener()`

this will trigger when ad failed to receive

```
mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onAdLoaded() 
   {
       // Toast.makeText(First.this, "The interstitial is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
       button_go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
       button_loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onAdClosed() 
   {
       go_action();
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode error) {
     // add your code here 
   }    
});
```

Comment: i have imported import `com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;`
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;`
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;`
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;`
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;`
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherInterstitialAd;`

Comment: this is the import for Ad `import com.google.ads.Ad;` look at my answer now.

Comment: thx for your help...I have added `import com.google.ads.Ad;` but it turns to `The import com.google.ads.Ad cannot be resolved`..is there any differences for mixing for Admob SDK (Google Play) and Android (6.4.1 and earlier SDKs)? I am using Admob SDK (Google Play) for the current version

Comment: Something wrong in you jar file, remove it and add again and try, i am using this GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 it's working fine in android versions 8 - 17. otherwise update your sdk manager properly and then try.

Comment: yes, I am not using Android (6.4.1 and earlier SDKs) but instead using  Admob SDK (Google Play) in a view that 6.4.1 will be not supported half year later. There is no jar file for this newer one but instead to use a `google-play-service_lib library

Comment: If that is the case i am not sure about this imports, as of now i am working on GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1. it's fine.